# Charts (ColumnChart, BarChart, LineChart, AreaChart etc.) - Save as Image without ScrollBar

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have one problem related to charts.

I have Column chart with 1000+ columns on it with the scroll bar on it. Now I want to save it as Image to my Disktop or any location without scroll.

**ScrollableAxisRenderer Class** I have Downloaded from one of the link please find it below: -
http://www.connectedpixel.com/blog/scrollingcharts

**Sample Column Chart Example: -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="init();" xmlns:charts="com.connectedpixel.charts.*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:XML xmlns="" id="myData">
            <items>
                <item year="1960" rain="92" />
                <item year="1961" rain="192" />
                <item year="1962" rain="32" />
                <item year="1963" rain="52" />
                <item year="1964" rain="112" />
                <item year="1965" rain="52" />
                <item year="1966" rain="88" />
                <item year="1967" rain="52" />
                <item year="1968" rain="66" />
                <item year="1969" rain="39" />
                <item year="1970" rain="192" />
                <item year="1971" rain="182" />
                <item year="1972" rain="177" />
                <item year="1973" rain="179" />
                <item year="1974" rain="198" />
                <item year="1975" rain="207" />
                <item year="1976" rain="388" />
                <item year="1977" rain="372" />
                <item year="1978" rain="352" />
            </items>
        </fx:XML>

        <s:XMLListCollection id="rainData" source="{myData.children()}" />

    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;
            import mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder;

            protected function initCreationComp():void
            {
                var image:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(myChart,300,new PNGEncoder(),true);
                var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
                var chartName:String = "myChart"+count+".png";
                file.save(image.data, chartName);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" x="50" y="50">
        <s:Button label="Download Image" click="initCreationComp()"/>

        <mx:ColumnChart id="myChart" name="myChart"  
                        width="80%" height="80%" 
                        dataProvider="{myData.children()}" 
                        showDataTips="true" maxColumnWidth="35">
            <mx:horizontalAxis>
                <mx:CategoryAxis id="yearAxis"  categoryField="@year"   />
            </mx:horizontalAxis>

            <mx:series>
                <mx:ColumnSeries xField="@year"  yField="@rain" displayName="Rain" />
            </mx:series>

            <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
                <charts:ScrollableAxisRenderer id="scrollAxisRenderer" axis="{yearAxis}" tickPlacement="none"   
                                               placement="bottom" labelGap="3" maxVisibleColumns="4"/>
            </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>

        </mx:ColumnChart>
    </mx:VBox>
</s:Application>
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the chart inside container which will show scrollbars instead of your chart:

```
<mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" x="50" y="50">
    <s:Button label="Download Image" click="initCreationComp()"/>
    <mx:VBox width="80%" height="80%"
             minWidth="100" minHeight="100">
        <mx:ColumnChart id="myChart" name="myChart"  
                        dataProvider="{myData.children()}" 
                        showDataTips="true" maxColumnWidth="35">
         <!-- etc -->
        </mx:ColumnChart>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:VBox>
```

Comment: I have tried above suggestion previously, but I am not sure if it is good idea or good practice. I have multiple charts which will get displayed on user request. As whole code will get reputedly written in above case. 
I have tried below which does not solve problem: -

ObjectUtil.clone(), ObjectUtil.copy()

Is there way where I can create clone or copy of the chart and by changing dataProvider it should work, as I have multiple ColumnSeries which I am creating dynamically to my charts?

Comment: If you are doing it at run time you cannot convert chart to image instantly as it will be in result of blank save image on desktop.

Comment: Actually, I understood nearly anything. If you need multiple charts, rewrite your code in pure ActionScript to add charts dinamically or use Repeater or use something List-based with renderers. Never use ObjectUtil's clone and copy - THAT is bad practice defenitely.

Comment: For now i have implemented above suggestion by creating Dummy chart class which will will contain all my charts without scroll and passing dataProvider as input to that class on switch case. Thanks for your answer.